# Import Excel Data to Relational Tables of MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, stored-procedures, import

My excel workbook having three worksheets. Each Worksheet contains data for 3 separate tables of my sql database.

**Table1** : Client_master 
**Columns** : Id, Client_Name

**Table2** : compaign_master 
**Columns** : Id, compaign_Name

**Table3** : raw_data
**Columns**: id, date, client_id,compaign_id,views,clicks.

By using below code, i inserted excel data into mysql table.

```
use analyticsdata;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS excel_table;
CREATE temporary TABLE excel_table (
  id int,
  client_name VARCHAR(255)
) DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/puttaraju.d/Documents/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE excel_table 
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;

INSERT INTO client_master 
  SELECT id, client_name 
    FROM excel_table 
   ORDER BY id;
```

How can i read and insert data which is there in sheet 2 and sheet 3 to other tables.

Comment: there is a plugin called 'mysql for excel'. have you tried it?

Comment: @JayNirgudkar : i have to do this using stored procedure.Its my requirement

Comment: Unfortunately, the .csv format does not support the multiple worksheets that Excel has. You will need to save each sheet into their separate .csv files and then import them one by one. Alternatively, you can combine the sheets into one and then save that as a .csv file and import that. Try [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=151)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have 3 options (2 require plugins):

1. Install the Excel MySQL plugin http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/
2. Install the MySQL UDF plugin http://www.mysqludf.org/ write a shell script for transforming the Excel file to separate csv files (e.g. run an Excel macro) and run the script using 
   the "sys_exec" SQL command
3. Join all three tables into one CSV. Then upload the file to a temporary table (e.g. with varchar columns) and separate them on the column headers.

Comment: You mean to say i cant access individual worksheet in excel workbook. Thank you. I will go with option 3

Comment: According to my knowledge w/o additional software you can't.

Comment: Thank  you. i am going with option 3

Comment: http://Excel2MySQL.net utility is much better than Excel for MySQL plugin, however the plugin is free.